# Derivadas en matlab

Tags: matlab

Para hacer una integral en matlab podemos ejecutar lo siguiente:

```
syms variable

int(funcion,variable,a,b)
```

¿se puede hacer de igual modo una derivada de forma simbólica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Si. con  diff()

La funcion diff() tiene la siguiente sintaxis

> ```
>  diff(F)
>  diff(F,var) 
>  diff(F,n) 
>  diff(F,var,n)
>  diff(F,var1,...,varN)
> ```

*Para lograr lo que planteas:*

## Derivada de una función de una variable:

> ```
> syms x
> f(x) = sin(x^2);
> df = diff(f,x)
> ```

```
df(x) =
2*x*cos(x^2)
```

## Derivar funciones de varias variables

*encuentra la primera derivada de la expresión*

> ```
> syms x t
> diff(sin(x*t^2))
> ```

```
ans =
t^2*cos(t^2*x)
```

Como no se especifico la variable para derivar **diff** usa la variable por defecto definida por **symvar** para esa expresion la variable es x:

> ```
> symvar(sin(x*t^2),1)
> ```

```
ans =
x
```

Ahora para encontrar la derivada de la expresion con respecto a la variable t:

> ```
> diff(sin(x*t^2),t)
> ```

```
ans =
2*t*x*cos(t^2*x)
```

Con información traducida de [**diff()** en MathWorks](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html)

Comment: ¡¡Muchas gracias!!